# R: Create a txt file with the error handling of tryCatch

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I want to know if there is the possibility to create a log with the information of the "error" that force the tryCatch to do "error handling"?
Is to be able to gain visibility of potential errors. I want to avoid doing prints.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will work:

```
outputFile <-file("output.txt")
tryCatch({
  --- your code ---
}, error = function(e) {
   writeLines(as.character(e), outputFile)
})

-----------------------------

close(outputFile)
```

Comment: thanks! Question. The output file is an actual file or when you put file it generates it automatically? Other question. The information would be the error right? Or it will be able to tell you more. Like for example. This is in a loop. can it give the information in what index it fails?

Comment: 1. the file will be automatically generated. 2. yes, in my example the information is the error-message. but you can write in the file what you want. if you are in a loop you can write `writeLines(paste0("at index/step ", i, " occurred following error ", as.character(e) )`.

Comment: Follow up question. If I i have a nested tryCatch. How can I pass directly the "inner" TryCatch error, without doing any handling? I try to pass it as error=function(e){e}. But it pass it as a text of the class error. But the outer TryCatch does not treat it as an error.

Comment: @donpresente please edit your question and add a demo-code so that I'll be able to help you

Comment: There are packages now to easily log errors (or more common: conditions), e.g. `futile.logger` or `tryCatchLog`